# Export a single column to CSV from a list without comas

Tags: python, csv

I've done researchs and tried to correct my problem but really don't understand where the issue is. In this script I rearrange the first row of try.csv, and then would like to export it to CSV (try2.csv). The print function gives me for each line the correct and desired output, such as :

```
Gel%20lavant%20sans%20savon%20-%20500%20mL%20Natessence
Lait%20corps%20hydratant%20Hydra%20Aloé%20Vera%20-%20500%20mL%20SOBiO%20étic
```

However, output is like that for the exact same lines into CSV file:

G,e,l,%,2,0,l,a,v,a,n,t,%,2,0,s,a,n,s,%,2,0,s,a,v,o,n,%,2,0,-,%,2,0,5,0,0,%,2,0,m,L,%,2,0,N,a,t,e,s,s,e,n,c,e
L,a,i,t,%,2,0,c,o,r,p,s,%,2,0,h,y,d,r,a,t,a,n,t,%,2,0,H,y,d,r,a,%,2,0,A,l,o,é,%,2,0,V,e,r,a,%,2,0,-,%,2,0,5,0,0,%,2,0,m,L,%,2,0,S,O,B,i,O,%,2,0,é,t,i,c

Here is my code : I'm iterating through the list item. I also tried to export all lines with writerows, without iterating and got the same result.

```
import csv

data_to_compile = []
with open("try.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as data_base:
reader = csv.reader(data_base, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    if row:
        data = row[0].replace("'","").replace(" ","%20")
        data_to_compile.append(data)

print(data_to_compile)


with open("try2.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline='') as attempt:
writer = csv.writer(attempt)
for data in data_to_compile:
    print(data)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

Do you know where is the problem ? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
writer.writerow(data)
```

With

```
writer.writerow([data])
```